# distance of a two dimension parity check code

Tags: coding-theory

Is there any hint to find that d(C) = 4 where C is a two dimensional parity check code?

I know the first step is to show that $d(C)\geq4$, then by finding an example to show that $d(C) = 4$. But I am unable to show that $d(C)\geq 4$, is there any hint?

Comment: Do you know about product codes? Or more simply, can you prove that every row must have even weight and so must every column?

Comment: because every row itself is an even parity check code and every column is also an even parity check code. But then how do I proceed?

Comment: So each nonzero row must have (at least) two 1s in it as must each nonzero column. Maybe drawing a picture of the array might help here.

Comment: why can't it must be nonzero row?

Comment: You are looking for a non-zero word. So *some* row must be non-zero. It must have at least two 1s on some columns. Those columns are thus non-zero. They must have an even number of 1s.